# Assets file project.assets.json doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0/win-x64'

Tags: .net-core, msbuild, nuget, azure-pipelines, msix

I have a .NET 6 Windows Desktop app that I deploy with MSIX.

I can run and debug it on my own computer, but it fails to build with Azure Pipelines YAML.

I get the error:

> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5):
> error NETSDK1047: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\MyApp\obj\project.assets.json'
> doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0/win-x64'. Ensure
> that restore has run and that you have included
> 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
> You may also need to include 'win-x64' in your project's
> RuntimeIdentifiers.

App project file:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
<Platforms>x64</Platforms>
```

Installer project file:

```
<TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.19041.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.19041.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

The pipeline task is VSBuild with Visual Studio 2022 (v. 17)
Nuget tool is version 6.0 installed with NugetToolInstaller task.

Azure Windows agent uses vmImage: 'windows-2022'

The error says:

> Ensure that you have included 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0' in the
> TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include
> 'win-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.

I have added 'net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0' in the TargetFramework for both the app and the installer projects.

If I replace `win10-x64` with `win-x64` it can build, but I need to use `win10-x64` because one of the packages requires it (Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK with System.Management.Automation).

NEW:
After adding `/p:RestoreLockedMode=true` in the VS Build task, I now get the error:

> MyApp.Installer.wapproj : error NU1004: The project MyApp has no
> compatible target framework. The packages lock file is inconsistent
> with the project dependencies so restore can't be run in locked mode.
> Disable the RestoreLockedMode MSBuild property or pass an explicit
> --force-evaluate option to run restore to update the lock file.

NEW NEW: I upgraded to .NET 7 but get the same error.

How do I fix the error?

Comment: You ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Sadly no.......

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No..............

Comment: Waiting for solution too, someone help us :(

Comment: Same issue here

Comment: Maybe create an issue at the Nuget github, they are experts... then link it here...

Comment: issue happened to me when I cross compiled (target linux-x64) from windows and set Framework-dependent, gone away by making the app Self-Contained