# Assets file project.assets.json doesn't have a target for 'net6.0' - VS2022

Tags: .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Just a few days ago got this error, after updating to Visual Studio Community 2022 v17.2 (from v17.1.6):

> Error NETSDK1005
> Assets file 'C:.........XXXXXX.Web\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. XXXXXX.Web C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.300\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets 267

- Uninstalled everything related with VS2022 + Installer
- Rebooted
- Fresh Git Cloned the project I'm working on (I work on several computers all with Win 10 and all with the latest updates, this is the only VS installation that presents this problem)
- Reinstalled VS 2022 v17.2 (with .NET 6.0, the usual install)

The .csproj file has everything in place:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);(SpaRoot)\**\node_modules\**;</DefaultItemExcludes>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Always delete the 'bin' and 'obj' folders before build or rebuild....

Cannot get away with the compilation, and always receiving that NETSDK1005 error...

P.S. - already checked question [70711153](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70711153/assets-file-project-assets-json-doesnt-have-a-target-for-net6-0-windows10-0-19/)

Comment: My peer had same problem, made him -> signout of all accounts from the Visual Studio -> Close VS -> Reopen VS -> Signin with account that can access Nuget and that fixed for him

Comment: In my case I had to update the .pubxml file to the correct [Target Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74964417/1819403)

Comment: I changed publish setting "Modo de implementación" = "Independiente" (deployment mode = Independent)

Comment: I was getting this error when trying to do an iOS release build with .net7.  and finally found a workaround: I had to remove all target frameworks except net7.0-ios from TargetFrameworks in my proj file when doing a release build.  So it looks like: <TargetFrameworks>net7.0-ios;</TargetFrameworks> (note: I needed to do this in my main app project and also in a dependant class library proj.

Comment: I was getting this error because I had other projects in the solution... a web site, an api, and two class libraries in addition to the .NET MAUI application... I removed those and it built. <i>Strange</i>

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I found the problem and it indeed had to do with restoring NuGet Packages, in that I have a connection to a corporate NuGet repository, and the call to it was breaking due to wrong credentials.

What was troubling was that the error did not identify the nature of problem with the connection or the username of the credentials getting refused.

On the logged in user popup dialog window, where the several used usernames are presented, there was one username that was required to re-enter its password.

That was all it took.

**Visual Studio > Tools > Options > Azure Service Authentication. ReBuild and the NuGet Packages will be restored and build successful.**

Comment: I faced the same error and reapplying creds fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: This didn't help me. Still got the same errors.

Comment: Thank you for answering, solved my problem. If you are using Rider IDE you can try to run dotnet build --interactive instead. I was getting this warning in the build output:

The plugin credential provider could not acquire credentials. Authentication may require manual action. Consider re-running the command with --interactive for `dotnet`, /p:NuGetInteractive="true" for MSBuild.

Comment: Also occurs if you have a corporate NuGet repo and your VPN connection isn't active.

Comment: This & close & reopen VS did the trick.

Comment: IF YOU HAVE JUST UPGRADED FROM .NET 6 TO .NET 7 and you get this error when you are trying to publish .. then you are getting it cos you forgot to change the Target Framework in the publish target to .net 7... Dohhhhhhhh... Kudos to Anthony Griggs above whose comment got me to twig that...

Answer (score 49):

We had this issue in our Azure DevOps pipeline and it ended up being that the "NuGet Restore" task was using an old version of NuGet. You can see which version the pipeline is using if you check the logs for the "NuGet Restore" task and look for the "Detected NuGet" line.
We:

- added in the ["NuGet Tool Installer"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/nuget?view=azure-devops) task before the "NuGet Restore" task
- Under the "Version of NuGet.exe to install", list the version you want to use, or the minimum version (e.g. >=6.1.0)
- (this step is possibly overkill) Under the "NuGet Restore" Task, check "Disable local cache"

Comment: this was the solution for me when using azure devops pipelines

Comment: This also worked for me (without having to use "Disable local cache").

Comment: I use NuGetToolInstaller@1 without specifying the version but check latest is true. this step is run successfully but after I try to restore Nuget using DotNetCoreCLI@2 it is also successfully restored but I am getting the same error in the next dotnet publish command. Can anyone tell me what is the better way to restore the NuGet.either  dotnet restore, NuGetCommand@2, or DotNetCoreCLI@2

Comment: Switching to a new version of the nuget installer that automatically updates itself fixed the issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

For me, this happened after switching from .net6.0 to .net 7.0 in asp.net core / blazor project. The error occured when trying to publish the project to IIS.
Solution was to switch the "target framework" in the publishing configuration (.pubxml) in the "Publish"-tab.
[image]

Answer (score 20):

This happens because NuGet writes a file named project.assets.json in the obj\ folder & the .NET SDK uses it to get information about packages to pass into the compiler. In .NET 5, Nuget added a new field called TargetFrameworkAlias, and thus in MSBuild versions < 16.8 or NuGet versions < 5.8, it is possible that you can generate an assets file without the TargetFrameworkAlias as it will read the property and not find it.

You can resolve this issue by ensuring you are on MSBuild version 16.8+ & using NuGet version 5.8+.

In my case I have commented out the TargetAlias line and it published successfully.

Reference: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/error-netsdk1005-assets-file-projectassetsjson-doe/1248649

[image]

Comment: I like that you also explain things,  not only provide a solution. Thanks!

Comment: We had a very similar issue using VS2022 build tools. Switching the project to     <TargetFrameworks>net6.0</TargetFrameworks> instead of     <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework> fixed the issue

Comment: I have no targetAlias in any of my assets files and it still fails.

Comment: For me this did not work, the version of msbuild something v17.6. And the fix for that was published 2020. So I don't know, whether this has worked for anybody here. TargetFrameworkAlias was not set in my project...

Answer (score 15):

For me this fix worked:

If you don't have the dotnet cmd line tool, download and install the .NET 6 SDK.

Open a cmd prompt and run the command:

```
 dotnet restore <path to your solution>
```

(for instance: dotnet restore c:\app\myapp.sln)

Comment: Note that you must run the restore using the dotnet CLI. The available nuget tools in VS GUI won't fix the issue.

Answer (score 7):

For me, I was getting this when updating my projects from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 6. I had my .NET 6 code in another Git branch and when I switched from the main 3.1 branch to the 6 branch and then tried to build the solution, I would get that message.

After some trial and error, the solution that worked for me was doing the Git checkout and the restore via command line.

1. Close the solution
2. From the Developer Powershell (or using regular Powershell or the Visual Studio 2022 Command Prompt), navigate to the local directory that has your repo, and then:

   `git checkout [branch name]`

   `dotnet restore`
3. Then back in Visual Studio, reopen the solution and build, which would work.

Comment: "dotnet restore" was the golden ticket. Thank you!

Comment: I tried right-clicking on my Solution and doing "Restore NuGet Packages" but VS2022 said there was nothing to restore. So I: 1) Exited VS2022. 2) Navigated to C:\Users\{my_user_name}\.nuget\packages 3) Deleted all sub-folders. 4) Re-started VS2022. 5) Re-opened Solution. VS2022 auto-restores the deleted NuGet Packages and apparently repairs problems in the process so strangely everything worked after that!

Answer (score 6):

we got this problem when added cache on gitlab, and started to use dotnet restore,
it happend because we missed the "runtime" parameter to the restore command,

```
- dotnet restore --packages .nuget --runtime win-x64
- dotnet publish --no-restore --runtime win-x64
```

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the below mentioned issue while deploying to the simulator

> /../obj/project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for
> 'net7.0-ios/ios-arm64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have
> included 'net7.0-ios' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You
> may also need to include 'ios-arm64' in your project's
> RuntimeIdentifiers. (NETSDK1047)..

Adding the  `<RuntimeIdentifier>ios-arm64</RuntimeIdentifier>` leading some other error.  This issue mostly related to package restore.

Below steps worked for me:

- Delete bin and obj for the host project.
- Right click solution and restore package.(While restoring if target changes to generic device then set it to simulator and restore)
- If again target changes to 'generic device' then Quit VS and repeat above steps
- Deploy now.

Comment: Just manually deleting the bin and obj directories of the project with the error finally fixed it for me. And I was already at the point where I rolled back from .net8.0 to .net7.0 and couldn't build the old solution anymore. Build->Clean Solution didn't work and neither did all the nuget restore suggestions because VS kept on saying there's nothing to restore. Now I'm going to try and roll forward to .net8.0 again. Thanks for the first tip.

Answer (score 4):

I got this error after upgrading a .net 6 project to .net 8.
It was because i had not changed the target framework in the publish profile to net8.0. So publish works fine after i changed the value.

Comment: This was my exact problem, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I recently encountered the similar issue upgrade to .NET 8. I fixed this issue by just close my Visual Studio and reopen then build again. I know it sounds silly, but it works for me at the end. I hope if never tried this 101 troubleshooting approach, give it a go to see if works.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have a target framework for the system you are running on.
If you're running on mac, add a target framework for maccatalyst 
`<TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>`

In my case I had the issue on a .Net Maui app with net8.0 unit tests. I was building only iOS and Android. However, the tests were running on a mac, so I had to have a target framework for maccatalyst. Otherwise. I received

> doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-ios/ios-arm64'

Adding the maccatalyst target fixed the issue.

Comment: are you using the <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks> and <OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net8.0'">Exe</OutputType> workaround in your csproj file?

Comment: @michaelg yes, plus net8.0. So it's 
<TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst;net8.0</TargetFrameworks> and 
<OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0'">Library</OutputType>
<OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net8.0'">Exe</OutputType>

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem in Azure Devops, using a Windows 2019 build server with VisualStudio 2022

Error:
##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.301\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): Error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'C:\agent\vso_work\4\s<..>.API\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.

Resolved by adding a "NuGet Tool Installer" using version >=6.0.0
Before the NuGet restore task

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvxPV.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had this bug in a solution with several SDK plus non-SDK C# projects.

What fixed my case:

1. Close the solution.
2. Separately open the first project of the solution that Visual Studio failed to build.
3. Build the project.   --> *"Error not found and build is OK"*
4. Reopen solution.  --> *"Error disappeared"*

Answer (score 1):

***nuget restore*** resolved the same issue
and/or ***dotnet restore***

Answer (score 1):

For me, it works to set the target framework to another framework like .NET Core 3.1, build the application, set the framework to the original framework and rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem ("...\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0'. Ensure that restore...") with clean batch compilation of my sln: msbuild 17.4, nuget 4.7.

I replaced string

`nuget.exe restore my.sln`

with string

`msbuild.exe my.sln /t:Restore`

that was before

`msbuild.exe my.sln /t:Build`

and everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was directly due to an invalid Package Version value. E.g., instead of `1.2.2-beta`, I inadvertently had it as `1.2.2.beta` instead. Once I corrected it to a properly formatted value, the project/package compiled successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to build my .Net Core MVC locally via VS. Everything is fine. But I got this error when I pushed it to Azure Dev Ops. **Finally, I addressed this issue by aligning the NuGet versions.**

My local NuGet Version is 6.6.0. The ADO NuGet version, however, is 5.5.1.

I changed ADO pipeline NuGet version to 6.6.1 (somehow ADO pipeline task doesn't support 6.6.0 so I chose the closest one.). The error disappeared then.

Comment: I changed to nuget 6.2.1 and It worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I ran the `dotnet publish` command with `--no-restore` option like below -

```bash
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release --self-contained --no-restore
```

Even though I ran `dotnet clean`, `dotnet restore`, and `dotnet build` command beforehand the error persisted. Dropping the `--no-restore` option from the publish command resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when publishing Web API to the cloud.
Use Tools ->Command line -> Developer command prompt in Visual Studio 2022, enter AZ login, and after login, restart the visual studio, it is working for me again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was I had updated the Nuget package version in one assembly but not in another, so check you have the same nuget package versions across your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had inadvertently added a couple of projects to the solution that were in another folder. I received no errors until I changed NET version from NET6.0 to NET6.0-windows on one of the projects. The solution then didn't build, with 100s of errors, but each individual project built OK.
I noticed that "project.assets.json' doesn't have a target" error among all the errors, pointing to the outside folder.
Bringing those projects into the solution folder fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error sometime back. This worked for me: Logout from visual studio and login to visual studio account

Answer (score 0):

I had an error:

> Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0' in the
> TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include
> 'win10-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.

I removed bin and obj folders for this project and rebuilt the project. dotnet clean, dotnet restore didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue occurred after manually migrating a WPF application (still based on .NET framework 4.6) to the new "SDK style" project format. I used a combination of the proposed solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43693591/how-to-migrate-wpf-projects-to-the-new-vs2017-format) for performing the migration.

I had also enabled the packages.lock.json file by using `RestorePackagesWithLockFile` and `RestoreLockedMode`.

Everything was working fine, but when the project was being built in the GitLab pipeline, the assets file error occurred, stating the following:

> error NETSDK1047: Assets file '[BlaBla]\obj\project.assets.json'
> doesn't have a target for 'net46/win7-x86'. Ensure that restore has
> run and that you have included 'net46' in the TargetFrameworks for
> your project. You may also need to include 'win7-x86' in your
> project's RuntimeIdentifiers.

I wondered about "win7" and "x86" since I had never specified this. Therefore, I ignored the proposed solutions from the error message and had a look at the project properties instead. It turned out that the **"Platform target" was set to "x86"**, which seems to be the default. **I changed this to "Any CPU"**, performed a rebuild, committed the changes and the pipeline succeeded.

After changing the target platform to "Any CPU" and performing the rebuild, the `packages.lock.json` was also modified. It had contained a section for `".NETFramework,Version=v4.6/win7-x86"` previously, but that had now been removed. Most probably, this was causing the build to fail.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had

`<TargetFramework>net6</TargetFramework>`

instead of

`<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`

in my .csproj. Surprisingly everything else has worked, short of publishing...

Answer (score 0):

My project was set to use .NET 6.0, and I had to get my aws-lambda-tools-defaults.json file to say "net6.0" for "framework" value. That's what fixed it for me.

The command failing was "dotnet lambda deploy-function"

Answer (score 0):

I got the error when upgrading from net5.0 to net6.0.

For me I had to change the

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0<TargtetFramework> to 
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0<TargtetFrameworks>
```

in my .csproj file.  I had it in 3 places (2 in conditional PropertyGroups).  Once I changed it my publish started working.

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' ">
   <!-- For publishing a single file exe -->
   <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
   <TargetFrameworks>net6.0</TargetFrameworks>  <=== this worked
   <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
   <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
   <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
   <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error this morning.
This worked for me: right click on solution explorer in visual studio -> 'Restore NuGet Packages'.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

One another reason just came across to this problem while upgrading an existing Xamarin.Forms project to Maui.
When you add a new Maui project or convert using the upgrade assistant, you may get this problem if Xamarin.forms project was using package.config reference instead of Project reference.
Even if you add a new project to the existing solution, it doesnt compile but if you open in a new solution it works. I have compared what what could be the difference and there is no difference.
Solution would be to upgrade from package.config reference to Project references first for nuget and then upgrade to Maui.
This could be also similar problem from older Blazor projects to net6 or 7 based projects upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen during publishing if your target framework becomes out of sync with the target runtime you have set. Double-check this as follows:

1. On the Publish page, click `Show all settings`.
2. If there is a compatibility problem, you may see a red exclamation mark (!) next to the Target framework value. Select a different framework.

You would see the error if, for example, you were targeting the Windows runtime (e.g., win-x64), but *not* targeting Windows for the framework.

Comment: In my case, I didn't have a publish profile.  Simply making a publish profile for the framework it didn't find fixed the issue.