# project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-windows'. in pipeline

Tags: c#, azure-devops, .net-6.0, .net-4.8

I am able to build the application in local, but it fails in pipeline, and below error message i am getting .

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): 
C:\Agent\1\s\my-Applications\Process\Executor\obj\project.assets.json' 
 doesn't have a target for 'net6.0-windows'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0-windows'
```

when i am running a .net 6 console app its running perfectly.

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

but windows targetframework doesn't work

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: Researched and found like similar issue of yours via this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72280776/assets-file-project-assets-json-doesnt-have-a-target-for-net6-0-vs2022  you can refer to.

Comment: @RoyWang-MSFT Actually i am ble to to build .net 6 console Appliation , but i got the error while using .net6_WindowsForm

Comment: Whether you are using DotNetCoreCLI@2 task when restoring? And could you modify your ticket with sharing the YAML file and do remember to remove any private info in the file.