# C# project with Target framework .NET 6.0 expecting netcoreapp2.1

Tags: c#, azure-devops, pipeline, .net-6.0, netcoreapp2.1

I've a VS solution having various projects, all of them targeting .NET6.0

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

It builds in visual studio without any problem, and writes the output to bin\debug\net6.0

However, in Azure DevOps pipeline, the build fails with this error

`##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): Error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'C:\Agent3\_work\142\s\*****\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'netcoreapp2.1'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.1' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. 2023-03-16T08:57:39.9848471Z C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): error NETSDK1005: Assets file 'C:\Agent3\_work\142\s\*****\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'netcoreapp2.1'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.1' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [C:\Agent3\_work\142\s\*****\*****.csproj]`

How can I find which dependency is expecting netcoreapp2.1?

Following tasks are in use in the pipeline

- NuGet tool installer 5.8.0
- NuGet restore
- Visual Studio Build  (Visual
  Studio 2022 - dev machine also uses VS2022)

Comment: Check that you are using appropriate target/task in Azure and that all packages are updated to corresponding version.

Comment: @GuruStron updated the post to include pipeline tasks used

Comment: Check this out,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72280776/assets-file-project-assets-json-doesnt-have-a-target-for-net6-0-vs2022

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by replacing Visual Studio Build task with dotnet Build task