# Multi-Targeting: Assets file 'project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0'

Tags: msbuild, csproj, multitargeting

I am developing a library, which had been previously available under net6.0 and now i need to also provide it for net8.0.
When i switched
from `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`
to `<TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>`
everything built and all tests passed.

But if I try to use multi-targeting `<TargetFrameworks>net6.0;net8.0</TargetFrameworks>` I am getting the following error:

```
Assets file 'C:\Users\USERNAME\source\repos\REPONAME\PROJNAME\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net6.0'. 
Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net6.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
```

What i tried so far:

-Worked through [this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72280776/assets-file-project-assets-json-doesnt-have-a-target-for-net6-0-vs2022), but without any success. While the issues there seem to be kinda similar, the solutions are not really helping me...

-Updated Visual Studio to 17.9.1.

-Read through some microsoft docs

-Exectue `dotnet build` to get more details

-Execute `dotnet restore` to get more details